# Move data from field to another field as a batch

Tags: extension, database, mysql, fields

I recently have taken over managing CiviCRM for an orchestra in Holland. Some fields have been used inconsistently, for example Nickname and First Name. I now need to copy all data in Nickname to First Name. That would be no problem running a SQL query, but I am afraid that would be too bold a step in CiviCRM. How do I go about? Is there an extension to do the job?

Comment: Why not just import the nickname field to first name field?

Comment: this is something we would likely do via an sql query - but you would also need to then update Display Name and Sort Name fields, so they showed the updated data, via another query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an extension but there is an api (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/). If you do it in SQL it wouldn't autoupdate other items like the "display_name", so you could write a little php script using the api to do it, and then run it with `cv php:script`. Basically you would want Contact.get and then Contact.create, e.g. something like (untested! Make a backup!)

```
$contacts = civicrm_api3('contact', 'get', ['contact_type' => 'Individual']);
foreach ($contacts['values'] as $c) {
  civicrm_api3('contact', 'create', [
    'id' => $c['id'],
    'first_name' => $c['nick_name'],
  ]);
}
```

You may also want to e.g. check that nick_name isn't blank for that record. May need to experiment.

FYI contact.create means "update" when you give it an `id`.

Comment: Great, thanks, I am going to work on it!

Comment: another option might be an export/import but would need to check how to deal with a field, eg nickname, which might have data but which should be overwritten to be NULL or empty

Answer (score 2):

You could do it just with API Explorer 4 using chaining:

[image]

I've added a couple of 'where' clauses for minor sanity - you might want to adjust those.

This finds all the contacts satisfying the 'where' clauses and for each one, runs an update where `$id` and `$nick_name` in the chain clause refer to the values from the contact just looked up.

Take a backup & test carefully!

Comment: Thanks for the great write up on how to do this